# hashtag and otherrs like at-key not working

Tags: keyboard

I just in installed ubuntu yesterday but my hastag key and at-key aren't working (and a few  other keys. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In your system settings you have a "Keyboard" section where there is an option to change the "layout" of the keyboard.
Make sure that the layout selected corresponds to the layout of your physical keyboard.

Comment: it is. but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Then maybe you should edit your question adding some more information, like: which layout you use? which type of keyboard you are using (the laptop keyboard, some external keyboard)? Do you use a combination of key to get the hashtag, like Alt Gr+something?

Comment: i use a azerty keyboard (belgian) and the normal way for getting a hashtag for examble is alt+ctrl+3(the 3 from the road directly under f1,f2 an so on)

Comment: an i use and it works fine! only some keys don't work when i unplug my keyboard and use the laptop one, it doesn't work aswell

Comment: i use a razer keyboard sorry for not being complete

Comment: > the normal way for getting a hashtag for examble is alt+ctrl+3 I tried your layout and with my laptop keyboard i can type the # with: Alt Gr+3
Try it